# Как организовать одновременную работу Telegram бота (Aiogram) и Flask?

Tags: многопоточность, telegram, flask, aiogram, асинхронность

Всем доброго времени суток!
Нужен совет.

У меня есть бот (написанный с помощью telebot) и API (Flask), которые запущены в двух потоках и спокойно работают одновременно. Бот запущен через polling.

API занимается обработкой входящих POST запросов с нескольких адресов.

Сейчас переписываю бота с использованием aiogram.
Знаю, что нельзя смешивать асинхронность и потоки, но возникает трудности с одновременной работой этих двух модулей. Работает либо бот, либо API.

Какие есть варианты подружить Flask и Aiogram, или же стоит отказаться от использования Flask и обрабатывать запросы другим способом?

Также читал про вариант с webhook`ами, вроде там можно отлавливать POST-запросы, и тогда Flask не нужен.

Пробовал вариант с запуском в разных потоках:

```
import threading
import time
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask,request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import config
import asyncio,hashlib,requests,threading,time
import logs
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from asyncio import new_event_loop, set_event_loop

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
dp = Dispatcher(Bot(token=config.bot_token))

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def message_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("HI")

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def get_test():
    data = request.get_json()
    print (data)
    return ("ok")

def app_run():
    while True:
        try:
            app.run()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

def bot_polling():
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
        set_event_loop(new_event_loop())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=bot_polling)
bot_thread.daemon = True
bot_thread.start()

app_thread = threading.Thread(target=app_run)
app_thread.daemon = True
app_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

Пробовал через асинхронность с помощью встроенной в aiogram on_startup:

```
import threading
import time
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import config
import asyncio,hashlib,requests,threading,time
import logs
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from asyncio import new_event_loop, set_event_loop

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
dp = Dispatcher(Bot(token=config.bot_token))

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def message_start(message: types.Message):
    print("hi")
    await message.answer("HI")

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def get_test():
    data = request.get_json()
    print (data)
    return ("ok")

async def is_enabled():
  while True:
    await app.run()

async def on_startup(x):
    asyncio.create_task(is_enabled())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: `возникает трудности с одновременной работой этих двух модулей. Работает либо бот, либо API.` - что-то делаете неправильно. Но что именно без кода нельзя сказать. Покажите минимальный самодостаточный пример.

Comment: @roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua, добавил код

Comment: Самое правильное и логичное - это просто отказаться от использования pooling-а, и перейти на webhook-и. В этом случае aiogram просто будет обрабатывать http-запросы по заранее вами заданному в flask-е роуту..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с потоками почти правильный. Нужно только loop создать до вызова `start_polling`:

```
        set_event_loop(new_event_loop())
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

С асинхронным тоже можно. Вот так будет работать:

```
...

async def on_startup(x):
    asyncio.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(app.run))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Есть только проблема с остановкой flask, есть способы и ее побороть.